# Zend Framework problems using Element, sub-forms and belongsTo

Tags: zend-framework, belongs-to, zend-form-sub-form

Still pulling my hair out with Zend_Form and any elements that need to be placed in a sub-array. form->populate() does not work when working with elements within a sub-form that have been set to a parent array using belongsTo() - I think it is actually a bug in Zend_Form->setDefaults() but just wanted to see if anyone else has a) had the same problem and b) managed to work around it...

Answer (score 0):

I usually do $form->subForm->setDefaults($myData) instead of belongTo(). But that was used in multipage forms so I never really needed to pull data for all the subforms...